# Per-transaction isolation level in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, transactions, django-orm

Is it possible to set isolation level for custom transaction (but not with raw sql)?

For example, something like:

```
with transaction.commit_on_success(isolation='SERIALIZABLE'):
    bla
```

Answer (score 28):

As far as I know, there's no way to temporarily change the transaction isolation level in Django for an existing database connection(s).

However, you could setup another database connection(s) that mirrors your default database connection(s) but sets the transaction isolation level.

E.g. in your settings.py:

```py
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'NAME': 'app_data',
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'USER': 'postgres_user',
            'PASSWORD': 's3krit',
        },
        'serializable': {
            'NAME': 'app_data',
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'USER': 'postgres_user',
            'PASSWORD': 's3krit',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,
            },
        },
    }
```

To use the serializable transaction level, you could:

1. Use the `using()` [QuerySet method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database)
   e.g. `User.objects.using('serializable').all`
2. Add a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) that specifies the database connection with the transaction isolation level

   ```
   class SerializableUserManager(models.Manager):
       def get_queryset(self):
           return super(SerializableUserManager, self).get_queryset().using('serializable')
   ```

Comment: Acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: One gotcha to keep in mind with such a solution is that one connection won't see any changes made by the other connection if those are made in a transaction and that transaction hasn't committed yet.