# Default isolation level for transaction (@atomic) with Django and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

I was wondering what's the default isolation level when using Django with PostgreSQL. *Serializable Isolation*? (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE)

There is a discussion about MySQL ([Django transaction isolation level in mysql & postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280779/django-transaction-isolation-level-in-mysql-postgresql)) but despite its name is doesn't seem to discuss PostgreSQL

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#isolation-level):

> Like PostgreSQL itself, Django defaults to the READ COMMITTED
>   isolation level.

Answer (score 5):

Django can be configured using the database settings like this:

```
import psycopg2.extensions

DATABASES = {
    # ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'isolation_level': psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE,
    },
}
```

Documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#isolation-level

Comment: It seems like **Django 3.2.16** has some bugs so your solution actually doesn't work even though the django documentation explains the same solution.

Comment: @SuperKai-KazuyaIto which bugs? Please provide an error message

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, Django's default isolation level depends on the isolation level which you set for your PostgreSQL. In other words, if you set `REPEATABLE READ` for your PostgreSQL with psql, Django's default isolation level is `REPEATABLE READ`.

With the raw query below, you can check the current isolation level of your PostgreSQL from `settings.py` in Django. *The raw query must be run after **database settings** otherwise error occurs:

```py
# "settings.py"

from django.db import connection

# ...

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    },
}

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SHOW default_transaction_isolation;')
print(cursor.fetchone()) # ('repeatable read',)
```

*`settings.py` is run every time **Django Server** is run with the command below or every time **Django Server** is reloaded by writing code so the raw query above is run every time **Django Server** is run with the command below or every time **Django Server** is reloaded by writing code:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

In addition, you can also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955733/how-to-set-repeatable-read-for-a-transaction-in-django) explaining how to set the isolation level of PostgreSQL from Django.