# Should I handle order number using the model's ID?

Tags: python, django

I've an personal ecommerce site.

I'm using the ID of the model as the Order Number. Just because it seemed logic, and I was expecting ID would increment just by 1 everytime.

However, I'm noticing that the ID of my Orders (of my Order model) had jumped twice:

**a) From 54 to 86 (32 of difference).

b) From 99 to 132 (33 of difference).**

Don't know why, don't know if I should use a custom field instead of the models ID.

I'm using Django 3.0 and hosting my project on Heroku.

**models.py:**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('recibido_pagado', 'Recibido y pagado'),
        ('recibido_no_pagado', 'Recibido pero no pagado'),
        ('en_proceso', 'En proceso'),
        ('en_camino', 'En camino'),
        ('entregado', 'Entregado'),
        ('cancelado', 'Cancelado por no pagar' )
    )
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stickers_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    shipping_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank = True, verbose_name= 'Correo electrónico')
    last_four = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_district = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ORDER_STATUS, default='recibido_pagado')
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    cupon = models.ForeignKey('marketing.Cupons', blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Order'
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def igv(self):
        igv = int(self.total) * 18/100
        return igv

    def shipping_date(self):
        shipping_date = self.created + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
        return shipping_date

    def deposit_payment_date(self):
        deposit_payment_date = self.created + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
        return
```

**View that creates the order:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def cart_charge_deposit_payment(request):
    amount = request.POST.get('amount')
    email = request.user.email
    shipping_address = request.POST.get('shipping_address')
    shipping_cost = request.POST.get('shipping_cost')
    discount = request.POST.get('discount')
    stickers_price = request.POST.get('stickers_price')
    comments = request.POST.get('comments')
    last_four = 1111  
    transaction_amount = amount  

    first_name = request.user.first_name

    last_name = request.user.last_name

    phone_number = request.user.profile.phone_number

    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    shipping_address1 = request.user.profile.shipping_address1

    reference = request.user.profile.reference

    shipping_department = request.user.profile.shipping_department

    shipping_province = request.user.profile.shipping_province

    shipping_district = request.user.profile.shipping_district



    order_details = Order.objects.create(
        token='Random',
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        phone_number=phone_number,
        email=email,  # Using email entered in Culqi module, NOT user.email. Could be diff.
        total=transaction_amount,
        stickers_price = stickers_price,
        discount = discount,
        shipping_cost=shipping_cost,
        last_four=last_four,
        created=current_time,
        shipping_address=shipping_address,
        shipping_address1=shipping_address1,
        reference=reference,
        shipping_department=shipping_department,
        shipping_province=shipping_province,
        shipping_district=shipping_district,
        status='recibido_no_pagado',
        cupon=cupon,
        comments=comments
    )

    ...
```

Comment: This issue happened on my site when i deleted objects from a model .. Never deleted an added Order after ?

Comment: @JimErginbash Not Order objects, but other models in the DB, some related to Objects model. So Order ID should have an incremental +1 order if never deleting an model? And in that case, it should be handled with a custom field that looks for the last Order created reference field and increment it by +1, to use this as Order number?

Comment: This has to do with database sequences, nothing to do with deleting. I'll write an answer to explain

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @OmarGonzales
If we assume that you created four Order models, deleted the fourth , and then created one more order, you'r ID's list will be like this : 1,2,3,5

This is a 100% behavior i experienced while using postgresql,

Comment: Never rely on the auto id field for this kind of thing. If you really need order number to reflect the real number of orders and increment, then yes, create your own field and calculate it yourself. Beware of multiple requests creating an order at (almost) the same time, make sure you wrap calculating the value and saving in a [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/)

Comment: @ivissani PostgresQL. Ty.

Comment: @dirkgroten exactly. Could you provided a detail answer? (Considering the edge cases where 2 or more requests are creating and order at almost the same time?)

Comment: @OmarGonzales What happens if you delete a single `Order` record from your database. Will that affect the order id of other records? Do they need to be re-assigned new id values?

Answer (score 2):

If you need consecutive numbering without holes you should not use Django's autogenerated `id` field as your order number.

In order to guarantee uniqueness even under concurrency Django creates a database sequence which is an object in the database that produces a new value each time it is consulted. Note that the sequence consumes the value produced even if it is not saved to the database anywhere.

What happens then is that whenever you try to create an instance and this operation fails at the database level, a number from the sequence is consumed anyway. So let's say you create your first Order successfully, it will have the ID number 1. Then let's say that you try to create a second Order, but the `INSERT` in the database fails (for example for some integrity check, or whatever). Afterwards you successfully create a third Order, you would expect that this order has the ID number 2, but it will actually have ID number 3, because the number 2 was consumed from the sequence even if it was not saved.

So no, you cannot use the `id` if you need to ensure there are no holes in your order numbers.

Now in order to have consecutive numeration you could simply add a column

```py
    order_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
```

question is how to properly set its value. So in an ideal world where there is no concurrency (two processes running queries against the same database) you could simply get the maximum order number so far, add 1 and then save this value into `order_number`. Thing is if you do this naively you will end up having duplicates (actually integrity errors, because `unique=True` will prevent duplicates).

One way to solve this would be [to lock your table (see this SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686204/django-orm-and-locking-table) while you compute and update your order number.

As I assume you don't care that the order number faithfully reflects the order in which orders where created but only that it is sequential and without holes what you can do is to run a query like the following inside a transaction (assuming your `Order` model lives inside an `orders` django app):

```sql
UPDATE orders_order SET order_number = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(order_number), 0) FROM orders_order) + 1 WHERE id = [yourid] AND order_number IS NULL
```

Now even with this query you could have concurrency issues, [since Django uses postgres default isolation level by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#isolation-level). So in order to make this query safe you will need to change isolation level. [Refer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386738/per-transaction-isolation-level-in-django-orm) for a way on having two separate connections with two different isolation levels. What you need to make this query safe is to set the isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`.

Assuming you were able to solve the isolation level issue then is the thing on how to run this query

```py
from django.db import connections, transaction
with transaction.atomic(using='your_isolated_db_alias'):
    with connections['your_isolated_db_alias'].cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('UPDATE orders_order SET order_number = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(order_number), 0) FROM orders_order) + 1 WHERE id = %s AND order_number IS NULL', order.id)
```

The snippet above assumes you have the order for which you want to set the order number in a variable called `order`. If your isolation is right then you should be safe.

Now there is a third alternative which is [to use `select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) as a table locking mechanism (although it is not intended for that but for row level locking). So the idea is simple, in the same way as before you first create your order and then update it to set the order number. So in order to guarantee that you won't end up with duplicate (aka IntegrityError) order numbers what you do is issue a query that selects all the Orders in your DB and then use `select_for_update()` in the following way:

```py
from django.db import transaction
with transaction.atomic():
    # This locks every row in orders_order until the end of the transaction
    Order.objects.all().select_for_update()  # pointless query just to lock the table
    max_on = Order.objects.aggregate(max_on=Max('order_number'))['max_on']
    Order.objects.filter(id=order.id).update(order_number=max_on + 1)
```

As long as you are sure that you have at least 1 order before entering the code block above AND that you always do the full `select_for_update()` first, then you should also be safe.

And these are the ways I can think of how to solve the consecutive numbering. I'd love to see an out of the box solution for this, but unfortunately I do not know any.

Comment: Yes, for this project  the order in which orders where created is not important. They are inside `Order` app. However, it would be nice if you consider an example where the project requires that the order reflects in which the orders were created. 
**How to add that query inside Django Project???**
Thank you.

Comment: That case is somehow simpler, because what I would do is simply order by `id` and assign order number according to the position of the `Order` in the resulting ordered queryset (too many orders in this comment :-P). Note tha this position does not change, ever, so you don't have concurrency problems as long as you work with commited data only

Comment: Well I wrote the comment and realised you could do the same here... so this is another option, which is basically to use [row_number()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) as your oder number

Comment: wonderfull answer. Let's wait to see if someone comes with an out of the box solution for this case. Thank you, again.

Comment: You're welcome, would love to see some out of the box solution!

Answer (score 2):

This will not answer your question directly, but still might be useful for you or somebody with a similar problem.

From the data integrity point of view, deleting potentially useful data such as customer order in production can be a really bad idea. Even if you don't need this data at the moment, you may come to a point in future when you want to analyze all of your orders, even failed / cancelled ones.

What I would suggest here, is to ensure that deleting not so important related models doesn't cause deleting orders. You can easily achieve this by passing [PROTECT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) argument to your ForeignKey field. This will raise ProtectedError when trying to delete related model. Another useful options are [SET_NULL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL) and [SET_DEFAULT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_DEFAULT) whose names speak for themselves.

By following this approach, you will never need to worry about the broken id counter.

Answer (score 2):

Let's leave Django, Python.

That is DB topic. Say - you start transaction, with new row in particular table. That means new ID. If you commit that amount of work - new ID is visible. If rollback happens ID is lost. From DB perspective there is no way to reuse that number.

Be aware that `select max(id) + 1` is bad practice - what if two transactions do that at the same time?

Other option is lock. I can see 3 solutions here:

1. Lock all rows in the table - that means - your insert time depends on table size :)

As a side note. If you go one by one to lock, be sure to sort all rows in the table to be sure there is no deadlock. Say you use Postgres, edit means row can be moved at the end... so order depends on what is going on with the data. If so two transactions can lock rows in different order, and deadlock is a matter of time. During tests, under low load - everything goes just fine...

2. Lock whole table. Better, since not depends on rows, but you block against edits as well.
3. Separate table for generators - each generator has row in that table - you lock that row, take next value, at the end of transaction row is released.

To all points. That means - you need short transactions. In web apps that is general rule. Just be sure create order is light, and most heavy things are performed as separate transaction. Why? Lock is released at the end of transaction.

Hope it explains the case.

In Django. Let's create model:

```
class Custom_seq(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    last_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Query for next id:

```
seq = Custom_seq.objects.filter(name='order sequence').select_for_update(no_wait=False).first()
new_order_id = seq.last_number + 1
seq.last_number = new_order_id
seq.save()
```

Why it works? Please note that at one time you are creating one order. It can be committed - so used, or rolled back - cancelled... both cases are supported.

Answer (score 0):

It is database internal behavior: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

> Important
>
> To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the
>   same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled back; that is, once
>   a value has been fetched it is considered used and will not be
>   returned again. This is true even if the surrounding transaction later
>   aborts, or if the calling query ends up not using the value. For
>   example an INSERT with an ON CONFLICT clause will compute the
>   to-be-inserted tuple, including doing any required nextval calls,
>   before detecting any conflict that would cause it to follow the ON
>   CONFLICT rule instead. **Such cases will leave unused “holes” in the
>   sequence of assigned values. Thus, PostgreSQL sequence objects cannot
>   be used to obtain “gapless” sequences.**

Comment: MySQL related info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes

Comment: Any "fix" to have progressive order numbers in that case?

Comment: Do you really need that? I most cases having a timestamp field it's enough

Comment: I'm using id of Order objects as the Order Number.  that's why.

Comment: Then I think you should implement the logic by yourself. Maybe just running a query like `select count(id) where id<x`